# What do we mean by “code of ethics or design” in software engineering?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, development-process

I am not clear on what we mean by code of ethics or code of design in software engineer. Does this mean writing your thought process on how you will code the feature? Or it is a way of saying what you have coded or will code.

The point where I am most confused is the real world, which is different than putting your thoughts in documents and saying it will work. Since coding details can change, I don't know what's the point of having a design before coding.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you see these terms?

Comment: My `Engineering ethics` subject has these terms but I do not understand actually where ethics or design is applied.

Comment: I'd suggest asking your teacher then :) In general, (work)ethics is usually associated with  doing your job as well as possible, avoiding any malicious intents etc. So, I don't understand what is meant by `code of ethics or code of design`.